# Give styles to a div when clicked jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div `#sideFilter.smallScreenFilter` which when clicked on I want to assign css to show

```
{left:0;}
```

How can I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/) :

```
$('#sideFilter').click(function(){
   $(this).css({left:0});
});
```

Note that I removed the `.smallScreenFilter` from your selector : If you want to have this event handler only if the class is present (supposing it might not be), add it back in the selector. If not leave it out : an id is unique and is generally the best selector.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#sideFilter').click(function(){
   $(this).css({left:0});
});
```

i don't think u need class here in selector...u can add it if needed